# When did the notion of the tangent space emerge?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, lie-algebras, math-history

When did the modern conception of/notation for the tangent space to a manifold come into use?

Comment: I'm uncertain, but it's possible that this would also get a reasonable answer at [hsm.se]. You might consider asking it there.